# Text to Speech in the browser?

Tags: javascript

I've seen it done (google does it with google translate) but are there any open source libs?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I doubt they're doing this in JavaScript in truth.  They obfuscate their code pretty well, but I bet that what they do is have a sound file served up after doing the text-to-speech on the server, just using JS to load the src url of the audio object.

Doing it on the server yields a bunch more options:
http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=open+source+text+to+speech

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.aspx

Comment: Actually, did you mean in javascript itself?  Can you return the output from the server?

Answer (score 0):

You must check this out http://thetutlage.com/post=TUT178 , it is 100% browser based using javascript and seems promising to me..